# ANTLR4 string parsing containing a dot character

Tags: antlr4

```
grammar h1;

column_name
    : '"' ALPHANUMERIC '.' ALPHANUMERIC '"'
    ;


ALPHA : [a-zA-Z]+ ;

fragment ALPHANUMERIC : ALPHA (ALLOWEDATTCHAR)* ;

fragment ALLOWEDATTCHAR : '-' | '_' | [0-9] | ALPHA ;
```

I am trying to match `"Hello.World"` where the `.` between the words is mandatory, however my grammar doesn't seem to work. How to fix it? Also if possible I want at least one character before and after the dot.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought you couldn't use fragments in parser rules.

Comment: This is correct. Fragment rules can only be used in other lexer rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to match `"Hello.World"` as a complete token. If not, let me know. For that a very simple approach is sufficient:

```
DOT: '.';
String: '"' ALPHANUMERIC ALPHANUMERIC* (DOT ALPHANUMERIC ALPHANUMERIC*)? `"`;
column_name: String;
```

Here's what the `String` rule does: first match a double quote, then a single alphanumeric char. After that match zero or more following alphanumeric chars until you either see a dot or another double quote. If a DOT was found, match another single alphanumeric char and then zero or more further such chars until a double quote is found.

Don't forget to add a rule for your whitespaces or you will have to handle them manually everywhere. Typically whitespaces are skipped or put on the hidden channel:

```
Whitespaces: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Here's the parsing result of this approach using a slightly more complicated input (`Hel-lo.Wo_rld`):

[image]

Comment: yes, I want at least one character before the dot and one character after the dot. And yes I thought it is simple and tried an approach similar to yours I got the following error `line 1:0 mismatched input '"Hello.World"' expecting '"'` I also copy pasted the solution you pasted and I still get the same error.

Comment: Same error persists. I am not sure exactly what is going wrong. It so simple but couldn't get it working. I am double checking and triple checking but still same error persists. I have assigned a variable like this `String columnName = "\"Hello.World\"";` and then setting the entry point here `parseTreeWalker.walk(new ParseRuleDefinition(), myParser.column_name());`

Comment: Let's first focus on the parsing step before asking a new question. Does your parser correctly process your test string now?